# Grunt: Task "grunt-bower" not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, bower

I want to install package [grunt-bower](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-bower) for my grunt by using `npm install grunt-bower --save`. After I install, I see package `grunt-bower` inside `node_modules`. Here is my `gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({

        bower: {
            dev: {
                dest: 'public',
                js_dest: 'public/javascripts',
                css_dest: 'public/stylesheets'
            }
        },

        watch: {
            source: {
                files: ['sass/**/*.scss', 'views/**/*.jade'],
                tasks: ['sass'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true, // needed to run LiveReload
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['grunt-bower']);

};
```

I have register this as on official page : `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower');` But when I run `grunt` command, I meet this error:

> Warning: Task "grunt-bower" not found. Use --force to continue.

I don't know why. Does I do something wrong ? Please tell me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined the task you want to run as `bower` and not `grunt-bower` therefore,

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['grunt-bower']);
```

should be

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['bower']);
```

Comment: oh. i understand. thanks :) So, can you tell me purpose of line: `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower');`   Why don't we just make: `grunt.loadNpmTasks('bower');`  Or we don't make at all ? thanks :)

Comment: `loadNpmTasks` loads a set of tasks into Grunt, the task provided from `loadNpmTasks` is named `bower` and what you're supplying is the config for that task. JSON does not support hyphened names as keys so that would be impossible.